# Unable to generate load in jmeter for PUT request

Tags: http, jmeter

I am performing load test for an api. I am passing a json blob as request body.
If i use POST method, i am able to generate a throughput 2000 requests/sec. But if i use PUT method, i hardly get a throughput of 1 request/sec.

I am using HTTP as protocol and UTF8 as content encoding. I have a header for HTTP request too. (Content-Type: application\json)

The thread group configurations are: 
No of threads: 5
Ramp up period: 1
Loop count: Forever

The environment is same for PUT and POST. All the parameters in jmx are same except method.
I am running jmx in non GUI mode.
I am relative new to jmeter. Do we have to do some settings for PUT which i am missing out?

Thanks,
Aniket

Comment: can any one please help me on this issue?

Comment: Even though you see a throughput of 1 request/sec using PUT method, do you get the correct/expected response?
you have to confirm the same for POST method as well.